# Facebook does not use article image

Tags: media, meta-tags, social-network

We installed the metatag module,
and we activated all metatag entries on the *modules* administration page.
On the module settings
we selected content type *Node:article* and went to *Open Graph*.
We edited the tag *image* with the value **[node:field_image]**,
the same for tag *image url*

In the page source, we checked the meta properties:
"og:image" content="https://*domain name*/sites/default/files/field/image/*name of image*.jpg"
"og:image:url" content="https://*domain name*/sites/default/files/field/image/*name of image.jpg*"
Using this internet address directly in the browser, the article image is displayed as expected.

Meanwhile, Facebook still does not show the article image. The main logo image is shown, even after emptying the cache of the Drupal site and the cache of the browser.

What does go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Having been through this before with OG tags and Facebook, if your site has been up and you verified the OG tags are in the source and work, then the likely culprit is that Facebooks crawler cached the page before you added the tag and you will need to wait a while.

If the image url resolves and the tag is right, it just takes time.

Perhaps try to look into using the Facebook debugger, something like in this article: https://www.braveriver.com/how-to-clear-facebook-open-graph-and-twitter-cards-cache-on-demand/

We saw this behavior with both Facebook and Twitter. IIRC it took about 3-6 hours to see them "appear" after initial attempts.

Comment: Thx for yr reply. Using the debugger, we got the error "The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id". Do we need to get some Facebook id?

Comment: I don’t think that’s required for OG tags to work.

Comment: We are now 6 days later, but the image, correctly defined in **og:img** and **og:img:url**, still does not appear on Facebook. Maybe the cache has not been cleared?